# Recommend manual SugarCRM for developer

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm an intern developer in a bank. Currently I develop custom things in SugarCRM. But I can't find a good manual about customization in SugarCRM ver. 6.5+.

Comment: This is, in any case, far too broad for Stack Overflow. It is much better to show what specific problem you have, what code you have tried in order to solve it, and what output you were expecting. If you just have a broad question, then read the official docs and/or buy a book.

Comment: Have you tried the Dev Guide? http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/

Answer (score 2):

You could check out the SugarCRM resources at https://university.sugarcrm.com/. Register and look through the site and you'll find webinars and videos on various aspects of SugarCRM, including its customization. It might help make interpreting the developer docs a bit easier. Note however the materials will be biased towards SugarCRM 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for custom development of modules in SugarCRM. 
Then there are so many online materials you can find but the problem is how good they are? In my opinion, following links have good content to read and understand.

1. SugarCRM Support
   http://support.sugarcrm.com/
2. News | SugarCRM Community
   https://community.sugarcrm.com/welcome
3. Sugar Developer Blog - SugarCRM
   https://developer.sugarcrm.com/
4. Blog - SugarOutfitters
   https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/blog